# thumbnail carousel for dynamic load

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

Hi guys I use **bxslidder** for responsive slider. It works fine with few slides; I would like to slide more images. Is there any plugin for it? Here's my link

http://www.mediaserveit.com/demo/vivek/cutout/gallery.php

Here I slide just four images i need to slide more help me out. and also for responsive.

my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.gallery_slidder').bxSlider({
 pagerCustom: '.gallery_paging'
   });
  });
</script>
```

my html

```
<div class="gallery_slidder">

    <img src="resources/images/foto.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="resources/images/foto.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="resources/images/foto.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="resources/images/foto.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
<div class="gallery_paging">
    <a data-slide-index="0" class="gallery_thumbs">
  <img src="resources/images/thumb_im.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" class="gallery_thumbs">
   <img src="resources/images/thumb_im.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" class="gallery_thumbs">
   <img src="resources/images/thumb_im.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="3" class="gallery_thumbs">
   <img src="resources/images/thumb_im.png" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.. what problem are you having? Do you want to make the bottom div with the four images scrollable, so that you can add more?

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis Yea i need to add more images on bottom to scroll.. :( how to add more scrollable images

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to what is commonly known as an image "carousel".

There are a lot of scripts that you can use for this, with the most known one being [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).

There are plenty of such plugins for jQuery, so I suggest you do a Google search. Here are some pages containing the best carousel plugins:

- http://inspiretrends.com/free-jquery-carousel-plugins/
- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html
- http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/

Answer (score -2):

You can also check out [designpotato](http://designpotato.com/10-amazing-jquery-carousel-plug-ins/) to solve the issue.